# Java to print number triangle with nested loop

Tags: java, for-loop, nested-loops

I am trying to print the following using a nested loop in Java:

1 2 3 4 5 6
   1 2 3 4 5
      1 2 3 4
         1 2 3
            1 2
               1

but it's coming out like the following:

1 2 3 4 5 6
   2 3 4 5 6
      3 4 5 6
         4 5 6
            5 6
               6

Here is my code:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
    for (int j = 1; j < i; j++) 
    {
        System.out.print("  ");
    }
    for (int j = i; j <= 6; j++) 
    {
    System.out.print(j + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You should use a different variable than `j` again in your print loop.  Hint: look what you set `j` too in there as well.

Comment: Use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks. The indentation of the code is intended to help people understand the program flow.

Answer (score 1):

```
int n = 7;

for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {

    for (int j = 1; j < i; j++) {
        System.out.println(" ");
    } 
    for (int j = i; j <= 6; j++) {              
       System.out.println(j +" ");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set this condition in inner second loop.

```
for (int j = 1; j <= 7 - i ; j++)
```

**Edit :**

Complete code is

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
    for (int j = 1; j < i; j++) 
    {
        System.out.print("  ");
    }
    for (int j = 1; j <= 7 - i ; j++) 
    {
        System.out.print(j + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Program should be -

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
    for (int j = 1; j < i; j++) 
    {
        System.out.print("  ");
    }
    for (int j = 1; j <= (6-i+1); j++) 
    {
    System.out.print(j + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 2; i <= 7; i++) {
    for (int j = 2; j < i; j++) {
        System.out.print("  ");
    }
    for (int j = i; j <= 7; j++) {
        System.out.print(j-1 + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is giving the same output ... Please check

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    { int c=0;

        for(int i=6;i>0;i--)
        {
            for(int k=0;k<c;k++)
              {
                  System.out.print("  ");
              }
              for (int j=1;j<=i;j++)
              {
               System.out.print(j +" ");
              }
              c++;
              System.out.println(" ");

        }  
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 7; i++) {
for (int j = 1; j < i; j++) 
{
    System.out.print("  ");
}
for (int j = 1; j <= 7-i; j++) 
{
System.out.print(j + " ");
}
System.out.println();
```

}

Comment: inner loop should be 6-i+1

Comment: Why did you changed the answer Again, i<=6 is correct, recent edit is wrong, Edit tht before somebody downvote

Comment: i<=6 will give output like 1 2 3 4 5... and not 1 2 3 4 5 6

Comment: I have already tested that, it will work for sure. so modify it, I haven't posted the answer, because you people already posted, so correct it...

Comment: Use this http://www.browxy.com/ compile your code, so that you can your wrong...I have already told you..

Comment: Am not saying you are wrong, my code works too as the condition in inner loop just fails for last iteration and hence generates correct output.

Comment: Thank you for the help everyone. Usually in stuff like this it is one small or minor thing that needs to change and sometimes when you stare at it for too long you just can't see the solution. This is one of those times.