# How to iterate for each e2 element after e1 element in List?

Tags: java, arraylist, iteration

I would like to iterate `e2`, which is element after each element `e1` in List.

I am looking for clean and correct way to implement the following:

```
For each element e1 in eList:
    For each element e2 after e1 in eList;
        algorithm(e1, e2)
```

What I did so far:

```
List<Element> eList = init(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8);
for (int i = 0; i < eList.size(); i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < eList.size(); j++){
        if (j > i){
            Element e1 = eList.get(i);
            Element e2 = eList.get(j); 
            algorithm(e1, e2)
        }    
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly prevents you from doing the usual `int j = i + 1; j < eList.size(); j++` and omitting the `if`?

Comment: ...can't even come up with a good duplicate for this one. [This maybe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15463925/java-to-print-number-triangle-with-nested-loop).

Answer (score 0):

How about something like the following:

```
List<Element> eList = init(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8);
for (int i = 0; i < eList.size() - 1; i++) {
    Element e1 = eList.get(i);
    for (int j = i + 1; j < eList.size(); j++) {
        Element e2 = eList.get(j);
        algorithm(e1, e2);
    }
}
```

The outer `for` loop runs up until the second last element to ensure there is always one more element to come. The inner `for` loop starts after the outer `for` loop's index and runs to the very end.